# .gitignore Advice for Android Project

Tags: android, git, github

Going to be versioning my Android project in git (and github), and curious if anybody has any advice on what files / folders I should be adding to .gitignore etc. Any gotchas I should be aware of?

I hate when I version my whole project then a few commits down the road end up with a bunch of files / folders in conflict I shouldn't have versioned in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Standard .gitignore for Android projects

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

Comment: @oneilse14 if there is not than one android projects in the same git repo, then this file is not enough and should be modify, since the bin directories may be in prj1/bin or prj2/bin ..., prjn/bin, etc, what it should be then?